# Unable to fetch data From Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I am trying to fetch my user's name and say hello to him/her whenever the app is opened. But I am unable to fetch data for a certain user based on their uid. The toast never actually shows up when I run the app.

Database Structure

```
"Users" : {
    "SeLT0H7Qz9aWUSIpXwbCquiLBkA2" : {
      "age" : 20,
      "email" : "xyz@gmail.com",
      "name" : "xyz"
    }
}
```

Code

```
ref.child("Users").child(uid).child("name").addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
           override fun onDataChange(ds: DataSnapshot) {
              name = (ds.child("name").getValue()).toString()
               Toast.makeText(baseContext , "Hello $name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
           }
           override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {

           }
       })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attaching the listener to the specific user's `name` property already, so shouldn't get the `name` property in the `onDataChange`:

```
ref.child("Users").child(uid).child("name").addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
     override fun onDataChange(ds: DataSnapshot) {
         name = ds.getValue(String::class.java)
         Toast.makeText(baseContext , "Hello $name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
     }
```

Comment: So could you guide me as to what would be the correct way to fetch the name value ?

Comment: That's what the code in my answer should do. What does `name` become for you when you run it?